# Как получить в Qt C++ данные о состоянии элементов из другого окна

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, как получить в Qt C++ данные о состоянии элементов из другого окна.
У меня есть два окна: mainwindow и smartsettings. При открытии окна smartsettings мне нужно получить в нем текущее значение из comboBox_23 окна mainwindow. Вот часть кода:

smartsettings.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "smartsettings.h"
#include "ui_smartsettings.h"

SmartSettings::SmartSettings(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SmartSettings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    if (MainWindow::ui->comboBox_23->currentText() == "FLAC") // *Здесь мне и нужно получить значение comboBox_23 (находится в окне mainwindow)*
    {
        ui->label_credits_16->show();
        ui->comboBox_26->show();
    } else {
        ui->label_credits_16->hide();
        ui->comboBox_26->hide();
    };    

}

SmartSettings::~SmartSettings()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "smartsettings.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
   SmartSettings smartsettings;
   smartsettings.setModal(true);
   smartsettings.exec();

}
```

Comment: передавайте параметром значение либо сам `comboBox_23`

Comment: А как? вот в чем вопрос... Если у меня comboBox в главном окне

Comment: Для класса `SmartSettings` добавьте параметр в конструктор либо в метод открытия окна.

Comment: У меня одновременно оба окна открыты, т. е. объекты уже созданы, просто через конструктор тогда как в этом случае?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос сведения: От какого класса наследуется `SmartSettings`? Как открывается окно `SmartSettings`?(покажите код)

Comment: Я обновил информацию.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от отношений друг к другу объектов этих окон и как один из вариантов вот так:

```
class SystemSettings : public QDialog {
public slots:
    void setComboBoxValue(const QString& value) {
        if (value == "FLAC")
        {
            ui->label_credits_16->show();
            ui->comboBox_26->show();
        } else {
            ui->label_credits_16->hide();
            ui->comboBox_26->hide();
        };
    }
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
public slots:
    void openSystemSettings() {
        SystemSettings window;
        window.setComboBoxValue(this->ui->comboBox_23->currentText());
        window.exec();
    }
}
```

А если окна открыты, то через сигналы/слоты:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
public slots:
    void openSystemSettings() {
        SystemSettings settingsDlg;
        // подписать на изменения
        connect(this->ui->comboBox_23, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged,
            &settingsDlg, &SystemSettings::setComboBoxValue);
        //  начальное значение
        settingsDlg.setComboBoxValue(this->ui->comboBox_23->currentText());
        // показать окно
        settingsDlg.exec();
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь получается окно smartsettings будет открываться каждый раз при изменении состояния combobox. Просто мне надо чтоб именно некоторая переменная в окне smartsettings получала текущий текст из combobox_23 окна mainwindow

Comment: @Maxim Timakov как только окно настроек закроется все удалится и не будет "висящих" ссылок )

Comment: Самое интересное как потом переменной "QString a", которая находится в smartsettings передать знаечние из combobox_23?

Comment: я обновил информацию

Comment: Сделал через глобальную переменную, вроде норм. Спасибо!
```
extern QString _combobox_23_value;

if (_combobox_23_value == "FLAC") ....```